# How can I understand which keyboard layout a MacBook pro 14 has based on producer code?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I'm in Poland and I want to buy a MacBook with a US keyboard layout instead of the ISO layout that is normally found in Europe.

The store from which I'm buying has those codes on their models:

(MKGT3ZE/A/P2/R1/US)

(MKGP3ZE/A/P2/R1)

I'm hoping that the ones with `US` at the end mean it's a ANSI keyboard layout. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it really was a US layout, if it has R1 at the end it means in Riot keyboard or something like that, but if it ends with US it has a US layout :)

Comment: No such thing as a "riot" keyboard.  R would presumably be Russian.

Comment: its not russian for sure lol

Comment: You are right, I found an online reference which indicates the /R1 model has the International English keyboard (which is ISO).

Answer (score 2):

If you order from Apple's Polish online store, you can specify the keyboard you want without worrying about the numbers:

[image]

Comment: that doesnt answer my question at all, but thanks